# Union in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, union

I want to achieve the following behaviour NULL AS (Oracle database):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cuentaahorroview AS
    SELECT IBAN as CCC, Interes, Ultimo_devengo
        FROM De_Ahorro
    UNION
    SELECT CCC, TIPOINTERES as Interes, null as Ultimo_devengo
        FROM CUENTAAHORRO@SCHEMA2BD2;
```

in a PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE VIEW EditorialView AS
    SELECT * 
        FROM dblink('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=bdp3e1 user=postgres password=1234', 'SELECT * FROM Editorial') 
        AS t1(nombre VARCHAR(100), CIF integer, ubicacion VARCHAR(50))
    UNION
    SELECT *
        FROM dblink('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=bdp3e2 user=postgres password=1234', 'SELECT * FROM Editorial')
        AS t2(nombre VARCHAR(100), CIF integer, NULL);
```

so as the union to work. How can I do it?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
psql:PR3_Vistas.sql:10: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 8:   AS t2(nombre VARCHAR(100), CIF integer, NULL);
```

Comment: Did you try running it? what happened?

Comment: @KaushikNayak question edited

Comment: Why are you trying to use "NULL" as a type?

Comment: I just want to make both sides of the union have the same number of attributes, as I did in Oracle

Comment: Replace `select *`with `select field1, field2, ...` and use `NULL as fieldx` in second part of union. `select *` is always bad in unions - you can't be sure that both tables have identical structure.

Comment: I promoted my comment to answer, you can act on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `select *` with `select field1, field2, ...` and use `NULL as fieldx` in second part of union. 
`select *` is always bad in unions - you can't be sure that both tables have identical structure.